# Text saved on a variable showing null values when i try to find a specific line

Tags: python, string, apache-tika, text-extraction

I saved a pdf content into a variable (called **CCR**) and when i print this variable, it shows the who**le text, line by line correctly**. Im trying to loop to find some lines that matches with a phrase but it shows me nothing. When i try to see what happens in this loop, i find that every line read from the variable looks empty.

```
#Extracting text and test

raw_CCR = parser.from_file(r'C:\Users\guerr\OneDrive\Documentos\PYTHON\ROOT_FILES\CCR.pdf')
CCR = raw_CCR['content']
print(CCR)


#Finding lines

key = "13.2"
linhas = 0
for line in CCR:
    linhas += 1
    print(linhas)
    if key in line:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

A part of the Loop. It finds nothing. The value "linhas" only helps me to know what is happening inside the loop

```
1
Not Found
2
Not Found
3
Not Found
4
Not Found
5
Not Found
6
Not Found
7
Not Found
8
Not Found
9
Not Found
10
Not Found
11
Not Found
12
Not Found
13
Not Found
14
Not Found
15
Not Found
16
Not Found
17
Not Found
18
Not Found
19
Not Found
20
Not Found
21
Not Found
22
Not Found
23
Not Found
24
Not Found
25
Not Found
26
Not Found
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `line` variable is actually going char by char. So your line var would be something like `t` then `h` then `e`, etc.

Add `.splitlines()` if you want to do line by line. I just tried this with `tika` on a PDF and it worked fine.

```
for line in CCR.splitlines():
    linhas += 1
    print(linhas)
    if key in line:
        print("Found")
    else:
        print("Not Found")
```

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like the issue might have to be with how your CCR data is formatted/organized.

Running a similar sort of loop using a random string and then converting that to a list (and then looping through that data using the same loop you have) worked fine for me.

```
s = 'Some random string or line with 13.2 in it'
>>> s = s.split(' ')
>>> s
['Some', 'random', 'string', 'or', 'line', 'with', '13.2', 'in', 'it']
>>> x = 0
>>> for line in s:
    x+=1
    print(x)
    if key in line:
        print('Found')
    else:
        print('Not Found')


1
Not Found
2
Not Found
3
Not Found
4
Not Found
5
Not Found
6
Not Found
7
Found
8
Not Found
9
Not Found
```

Maybe you could try splitting your data into a list by a newline character (\n) and then iterate through that to find the data containing the key you're looking for.